# copy commands from linux terminal to a word document in Windows

Tags: linux

I am using Mint through a VM.If I want to copy and paste command from the Linux terminal in the VM to a word document in Windows - so I'm going from Linux to Windows. How would I do that? The regular Ctrl + C then Ctrl + v doesn't work.
Thank you.

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to Linux and CL sorry if these are obvious questions. I'm trying to learn.

Comment: What virtualization (VM) software do you use? There might be some configuration to enable copy&paste between host OS and guest OS.

Comment: In my Linux box, when I startup a Windows VM, it usually works when I do exactly that, Ctrl-C followed by Ctrl-V in Windows. Please check that you have TWO-WAY mouse integration set in the VM-settings.

Comment: The setting can be found under [Settings] Advanced, Drag n Drop. Unusually I also have a bi-directional shared clipboard set, in addition to a bi-directional Drag 'n Drop.

Comment: Thank you both l  I don't think I have the TWO-WAY mouse integrated how do I do that?  and also where do I get the clipboard.

Comment: @Roadowl it worked!! I got it under advanced settings and changed both to bidirectional. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

often you use `Ctrl + Shift + C` in the terminal. `Ctrl + C` would interrupt the running task.